# Почему программа на Java может зависать? (REGEXP, m.find())

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Зависает программа в момент выполнения m.find() в случае, если строка в которой ищем, имеет большое количество символов. Возможно также наличие переводов строк.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Есть ли какое-нибудь ограничение на количество символов в String. Можно ли как-то обойти это?

```
private static String DLE = "DLE";
private static Pattern p;
private static Matcher m;
private static List<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();

//Тут формируются comments.add
//p = Pattern.compile(".*(?iu)(DataLife\\sEngine\\sCopyright).*"); // Было
p = Pattern.compile("(?iu)DataLife\\sEngine\\sCopyright"); //Стало
m = p.matcher(comments.toString());
if (m.find()) return DLE;

//Пробовал также искать подобным образом - всё равно зависает :( 
//for (String str: comments) {
//    p = Pattern.compile(".*(?iu)(DataLife\\sEngine\\sCopyright).*");
//    m = p.matcher(str);
//    if (m.find()) return DLE;
//}
```

UPD: Правильный код дописал выше. Было->Стало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

страно зачем вы вызываете ArrayList.toString(), потом чтобы оптимизировать выражение уберите .*, они жадны и матчат всю строку изначально, потом начинаются откаты для поиска `DataLife\\sEngine\\sCopyright`, и это может быть очень долгим процессом.

Comment: Спасибо, что помог разобраться!